# Dex2oatd Verification failed

Tags: android, google-project-tango, tango

There is a build error when preload app:

dex2oatd W 21386 21707 art/runtime/class_linker.cc:3126] Verification failed on class com.unity3d.player.o in /system/priv-app/Discovery/Discovery.apk:classes3.dex because: Verifier rejected class com.unity3d.player.o due to bad method void com.unity3d.player.o.()